# I want to update with string in a table with rdbms function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to update a table with a string with randomly with selection of rows with `rdbms` but it gives me error of `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`.
I tried to found where is right parenthesis is missing but didn't get this please help me regarding this I am selecting same table and want to update same table column
what I did is this

```
UPDATE PAY_IN_OUT
SET ATT_PRESENT ='L'
WHERE EMP_CODE = 
( SELECT EMP_CODE
    FROM   PAY_IN_OUT
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM )
WHERE  rownum < 40
AND ATT_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-09-01' AND DATE '2021-03-31'
AND  ((TO_CHAR(ATT_DATE, 'DAY'))) != 'SUNDAY';
```

Comment: You have two `where` clause which is not correct.  You have a subquery that probably returns multiple rows in a context where only a scalar subquery can be used.  The code has lots of issues.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok then what i can do i want to update `att_present` column with `L` on random rows what can I do dear please help me on this

Comment: From all the rows in the table between 2020-09-01 and 2021-03-31 except Sundays you want to pick 39 rows randomly and set their att_present = 'L'? Yes? What is the table's primary key?

Answer (score 0):

This statement would update some of the rows `ATT_PRESENT` to `L`.

```sql
MERGE INTO pay_in_out src
     USING (  SELECT 'L' AS NEW_ATT_PRESENT, emp_code
                FROM pay_in_out
               WHERE     ATT_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-09-01' AND DATE '2021-03-31'
                     AND ((TO_CHAR (ATT_DATE, 'DAY'))) != 'SUNDAY'
            ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
               FETCH FIRST 40 ROWS ONLY) d
        ON (src.emp_code = d.emp_code)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
    UPDATE SET src.att_present = d.new_att_present;
```

Comment: dear its doing first 39 some rows not whole table with random

Comment: @Zedan your original attempt included `WHERE rownum < 40`. Remove that condition if you just want to update all Sundays.

Comment: @EJ `to_char(att_date,'DAY')` might need to be `to_char(att_date,'fmDAY')`. Also the OP's double brackets aren't necessary.

Comment: @Zedan, I've updated the statement to use MERGE. This UPDATE should randomly select 40 rows from the table.

Comment: dear @WilliamRobertson I removed `WHERE rownum < 40`error is same

Comment: @EJEgyed respected it throw me error on `fetch` same right parenthesis error

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? This works on 18c: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=69096b928310242618aec488f03f2a67

Comment: @EJEgyed I don't think that `emp_code` is needed because we want randomly update `att_present` column from whole table so `emp_code` is not needed is that make easier

Comment: @EJEgyed Oracle 11gR2

Comment: @EJEgyed Yup on dbfiddle I checked if we use 18c its ok if we use 11gR2 then same error

Comment: @Zedan `fetch first` was added in Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you seem to want something like this:

```
UPDATE PAY_IN_OUT PO
    SET ATT_PRESENT = 'L'
    WHERE PO.EMP_CODE IN (SELECT PO2.EMP_CODE 
                          FROM PAY_IN_OUT PO2
                          WHERE ATT_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-09-01' AND DATE '2021-03-31' AND
                              TO_CHAR(ATT_DATE, 'DY') <> 'SUN'
                          ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
                          FETCH FIRST 40 ROWS ONLY
                         );
```

In older versions of Oracle, try:

```
UPDATE PAY_IN_OUT PO
    SET ATT_PRESENT = 'L'
    WHERE PO.EMP_CODE IN (SELECT PO2.EMP_CODE
                          FROM (SELECT PO2.EMP_CODE 
                                FROM PAY_IN_OUT PO2
                                WHERE ATT_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-09-01' AND DATE '2021-03-31' AND
                                      TO_CHAR(ATT_DATE, 'DY') <> 'SUN'
                                ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
                               ) PO2
                          WHERE rownum <= 40
                         );
```

This assumes that `EMP_CODE` is unique in the table.  If not, use the primary key for the comparison.

Comment: Respected sir your code is also working on 18C I checked on dbfiddle but not on 11gR2

Comment: @Zedan . . . That version is no longer supported.  But I added another version.

Answer (score 0):

From all the rows in the table between 2020-09-01 and 2021-03-31 except Sundays you want to pick 39 rows randomly and set their att_present = 'L'.

Up to Oracle 11 you had to use Oracle's `ROWNUM`, because the standard SQL clause `FETCH FIRST ROWS` was not available.

```
update pay_in_out
set att_present = 'L'
where rowid in 
(
  select random_rowid
  from
  (
    select rowid as random_rowid
    from pay_in_out
    where att_date between date '2020-09-01' and date '2021-03-31'
    and to_char(att_date, 'fmDAY', 'nls_date_language=English') <> 'SUNDAY';
    order by dbms_random.random
  )
  where rownum <= 39
);
```

In standard SQL there would be no guarantee that the subquery gets shuffled (because subqueries are unordered sets of data, so the `ORDER BY` clause can get ignored), but Oracle guarantees that, in order to make their `ROWNUM` method work :-)

`ROWID` is also Oracle specific. You can use the table's primary key instead, if you want to.

Comment: `'DAY'` should probably be `'fmDAY'` (or `'Dy'` as it's always 3 characters in English). Why Oracle pads the value with blanks we will never know.

Comment: @William Robertson: Correct, I completely forgot about those annoying blanks. Thanks. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson just a supposition on blank padding. Oracle V2 was released in1979. At that time the predominate output format was fixed length columns with non-proportional fonts. Space padding fits nicely with this style. So perhaps Oracle has just not updated. (They would claim backward comparability.) Oh well what's a programmer to do?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged PL/SQL, you could try a programmatic approach:

```
declare
    rows_updated number := 0;
begin
    for r in (
        select rowid as rwd from pay_in_out sample(10)
        where  att_date between date '2020-09-01' and date '2021-03-31'
        and    to_char(att_date, 'DY', 'nls_date_language = English') != 'SUN'
        for update
    )
    loop
        update pay_in_out
        set    att_present = 'L'
        where  rowid = r.rwd;
        
        rows_updated := rows_updated +1;
        exit when rows_updated >= 40;
    end loop;
end;
```

Note that `sample(10)` takes a 10% sample of the table. Whether this is too small or too large depends on  how many rows are in the table. You could query `user_tables.num_rows` to get an approximate count and then adjust it for the number of non-Sundays in your specified date range, if your stats are not stale, or you could count them.